Power BI - Creating new calendar based on the date ranges
I have a Reference table
Month        |    start date    |       end date

sept 2023 ,       01-09-2023     ,    25-09-2023,                                 
oct 2023  ,       26-09-2023     ,    25-10-2023,  
nov 2023  ,       26-10-2023     ,    25-11-2023,

dec 2023  ,       26-11-2023     ,    25-12-2023

I have a original date table:
Date = CALENDAR("2021-01-01", TODAY())

I want a new column which can adjust the dates as per the reference table. So September to start from 1-09-2023 and end on 25th of sept 2023. The next month to start from 26th of previous month and end on 25th of current month.
But I do not have any idea how to do this. I tried something like this
Month Period = 
VAR CurrentDate = 'DatesTable'[Date]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX('ReferenceTable'[Month]),
    FILTER(
        'ReferenceTable',
        'ReferenceTable'[start date] <= CurrentDate && 'ReferenceTable'[end date] >= CurrentDate
    )
)

But this return the month. And not the dates. I wanted the dates as per the ranges given in the reference table.

Can you please share your expected output ?

Expected output is
Before sept 25-09-2023 calendar remains same.
Now
26 -09-2023  assigned as 01-10-2023,27-09-2023 assigned as 02-10-2023,
28-09-2023 assigned as 03-10-2023,
29-09-2023 assigned as 04-10-2023,
30-09-2023  assigned as 05-10-2023,
basically new month to start from 26th ofthe previous month and end on 25th of current month.
I have tried like :IF( ActualDate < StartDate,   ActualDate,  IF( ActualDate <= EndDate,  ActualDate,  DATE( YEAR(ActualDate),  MONTH(ActualDate) + (DAY(ActualDate) >= 26, 1, 0), IF(DAY(ActualDate) >= 26, DAY(ActualDate) - 25, DAY(ActualDate) + 5) )

Let's assume that you want to have both fiscal & calendar months/years in your calendar table and that every fiscal month but September starts on the 26th of the previous month (September being your start of fiscal year), you can create these columns as follows:
Calendar month = MONTH([Date])
Calendar year = YEAR([Date])
Fiscal month = MOD([Calendar month] - 9 + (DAY([Date]) >= 26) * ([Calendar month] <> 8), 12) + 1
Fiscal year = [Calendar year] + ([Calendar month] > [Fiscal month])

No extra table is required.
NB: I've considered that the FY starting in September 2023 is FY24 but you can easily adjust it if needed.

Okay, thank you. But one more condition is there, these calculations should start from september 2023 . And before 2023 calendar should work as usual. That is starting on 1 and ending on 30/31st. How can i handle this exception

Does it mean that FYs always start in September (whatever the year) but that, before September 2023, fiscal months start on the 1st of calendar month?

Yes, the new calender has to be started from sept 2023. And before that everything can work as it is. Like January 2023 to start from 01-01-2023 and end on 31st january 2023, feb 2023 to start from 01-02-2023 and end on 28-02-2023.
This calender has to be start from 1st of sept 2023.  I do not know how to solve this problem , searching for it . can you help me please

Try this:
Fiscal month = MOD([Calendar month] - 9 + (DAY([Date]) >= 26) * (([Calendar year] > 2023) * ([Calendar month] <> 8) + ([Calendar year] = 2023) * ([Calendar month] > 8)), 12) + 1

@SantoshPal if this answered your question then please consider accepting it.
